# Java codes for USB

Tags: java

I want to create a program using Java for Automatically copied USB's data when it's insert to machine. How I do it?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  Why does it have to be in Java?  Why can't you use some existing utility for copying the USB contents?  Are you asking how to do the copying, or how to arrange that the copying occurs when the USB is inserted?

Comment: When you say "USB's data", do you really mean "All the files/data on a USB memory stick"?  Clear questions get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "USBs data", the very concept doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing specific in Java SE for do this job.

I may think of two ways to get that working:

1. Write a Java program that starts on boot (maybe a service), the prog scans continously available "drives" (D:,E:,F: ... in Windows, mount on Linux), the USB flash may be marked with a specific folder/file name (eg. **COPY_USB_**). That can be done with the [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/) class.
2. Write a Java program that get invoked on plug-in. I know that can be done on Linux with [hotplug-script](http://www.bangmoney.org/presentations/hotplug/) support.